# bombs in candy crush level 97

Tags: candy-crush-saga

in candy crush level 97,  my question is when a bomb Is colored green and you match 3 green candies that are not attached to the bomb, why does the bomb stay active, does the bomb have to be part of the match.  and do you have to deactivate the bombs in sequential order ???

a little confused on how this works

bill

Answer (score 4):

Level 97 is a real pain in the butt; it's one of the more popular levels to get stuck on.  The "bomb" mechanic is also not well understood by players, if [the comments on my guide are any indication.](http://www.withoutthesarcasm.com/how-do-i-clear-candy-crush-level-97/)

The bombs are like normal candy and *must* be cleared by the match you make in order to be removed from the level.  The most basic thing to do with them is to match them with two other like-colored candies.  You can also break them with special candies if you wish - so striped or wrapped matches will clear bombs if the reaction hits the bomb.

There is no requirement to clear the bombs in any particular order.  You can clear new bombs before old bombs if you wish.

However, if *any* bomb reaches 0, the level is over, done, you're dead, etc.  It does not matter if you had moves left or if you had already reached the score goal - bombs detonating means you **lose.**

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to find out how to destroy a Candy Bomb?

**There are a few ways to destroy a Candy Bomb.**

1. Regular Candy Match that is in sequence in that match. Basically the same way a normal Candy Match works.
2. A Special Candy of any kind. (Striped, Wrapped or Colour Bomb).
3. Lollipop Hammer (booster).

By destroying it you get 3,000 points, which is very helpful for level 97 especially.

**Here are a few tips for destroying Candy Bombs**

- Know when it spawns. At level 97, it spawns just about every turn. Some levels don't spawn them again.
- If a level spawns bombs often, try to keep candy matches closer to the middle. It's easier to destroy candies in the middle rather than at the sides.
- Having a spare colour bomb made could help aid you from low count Candy Bombs. When a Candy Bomb reaches a low count, use the Colour bomb on a candy that matches the same colour as the bomb and it will be removed.
- In some levels, destroying Candy Bombs may waste a few valuable moves. Only destroy them when you reach a low count unless it's a Moves Level.

The key strategy of level 97 is to destroy as many bombs as possible. They will spawn every 2 turns.

In addition to what **agent86** said, if a Candy Bomb reaches zero count, you will not die provided that the bomb is removed before the candies stop destroying. So yes you can hope for a bomb on the last move but try to destroy them when the count is very low.

If you'd like to read more about Candy Bombs check [here](http://candy-crush-saga.wikia.com/wiki/Candy_Bomb).